# Unable to ingest the syslog-logstash.conf for remove & replace functions

Tags: elastic-stack

I am just a newbie to the ELK and trying some testing on this, i'm able to run some tests but while i'm trying a filter with `grok` & `mutate` to remoev & replace some feilds from my syslog output i'm getting into below error..

```
21:58:47.976 [LogStash::Runner] ERROR logstash.agent - Cannot create pipeline {:reason=>"Expected one of #, {, ,, ] at line 21, column 9 (byte 496) after filter {\n  if [type] == \"syslog\" {\n    grok {\n      match => { \"message\" => \"%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:hostname} %{DATA:program}(?:\\[%{POSINT:pid}\\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}\" }\n    }\n    date {\n      match => [ \"syslog_timestamp\", \"MMM  d HH:mm:ss\", \"MMM dd HH:mm:ss\" ]\n    }\n    mutate {\n      remove_field => [\n        \"message\",\n        \"pid\",\n        \"port\"\n        "}
```

> Below is my config file ....

```
# cat logstash-syslog2.conf
input {
  file {
    path => [ "/scratch/rsyslog/*/messages.log" ]
    type => "syslog"
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:hostname} %{DATA:program}(?:\[%{POSINT:pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
    }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
    mutate {
      remove_field => [
        "message",
        "pid",
        "port"
        "_grokparsefailure"
      ]
    }
    mutate {
      replace => [
        "@source_host", "%{allLogs_hostname}"
        "@message", "%{allLogs_message}"
      ]
    }
    mutate {
      remove => [
        "allLogs_hostname",
        "syslog_message",
        "syslog_timestamp"
      ]
    }
}
output {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => "localhost:9200"
      index => "%{type}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
  }
}
```

please suggest what i'm doing wrong and  help to understand the remove & replace functions for the lagstash..

PS: my ELK version is 5.4

Comment: There is a comma missing after "port" in mutate filter

Comment: Sorry, i realise that .. even that is not working.

Comment: The config has lot of syntactical errors , Have posted my answer with explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Config you posted have lot of syntactical errors , the logsatsh has it's own config language and expects the config file to abide by the rule.
This [link](http://logstash-docs.elasticsearch.org.s3.amazonaws.com/_logstash_config_language.html) has complete logstash config language reference.

I made some corrections to your config file and posted here , Have added my comments and explanation of what was wrong in the config file itself

```
input 
{
    file 
    {
        path => [ "/scratch/rsyslog/*/messages.log" ]
        type => "syslog"
    }
}

filter 
{
    if [type] == "syslog" 
    {
        grok 
        {
            match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:hostname} %{DATA:program}(?:\[%{POSINT:pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
        }

    date 
    {
        match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }

    # Have merged it with the remove_field option below
    #mutate {
    #  remove_field => [
    #    "message",
    #    "pid",
    #    "port",
    #    "_grokparsefailure"
    #  ]
    #}

    mutate 
    {

        # The replace option only accept hash data type which has a syntax as below 
        # For more details visit the below link
        # https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-replace
        replace => {
            "@source_host" => "%{allLogs_hostname}" 
            "@message" => "%{allLogs_message}"
        }
    }

    mutate 
    {
        # Mutate does not have remove option i guess your intention is to remove the event field
        # hence used remove_field option here
        # The remove_filed option only accepts arary as value type as shown below
        # For details read the below link
        # https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-remove_field
        remove_field => [
            "message",
            "pid",
            "port",
            "_grokparsefailure",
            "allLogs_hostname",
            "syslog_message",
            "syslog_timestamp"
        ]
    }
  }
}

output 
{
    if [type] == "syslog" 
    {
        elasticsearch 
        {
            # The Hosts option only takes uri as a value type , originally you have provided string as it's value type
            # For more info please read the below link
            #https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-hosts
            hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
            index => "%{type}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
    }
}
```

You can test whether the config file is syntactically correct by  using logstash command line option -t this option will test and report the config file is syntactically correct

```
bin\logstash -f 'path-to-your-config-file' -t
```

Please let me know for any clarification

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a comma after "port" in your logstash configuration file.

```
   mutate {
      remove_field => [
        "message",
        "pid",
        "port",
        "_grokparsefailure"
      ]
    }
```